# runAction SKAction.sequence not working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I can't get the runAction method to work for this code block. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or if there is a problem outside the block, but if anyone sees anything inside that is wrong, let's start there **(*Edited to include entire function)**. All variables work and I'm getting zero compile errors, the program just appears to skip the line `currentTestIndicator.runAction(SKAction.sequence(runCheck))`. All print statements work except the one inside `recurse`, also `current++` isn't getting called. I tried running the code without `recurse` and it still didn't work. Ideas?

```
func runLevelCheck(node: SKSpriteNode, _ state: SKSpriteNode, _ bluePatterns:Array<Array<String>>, _ blueSize: CGFloat, _ blueLocations: Array<CGPoint>, _ greenPatterns:Array<Array<String>>, _ greenSize: CGFloat, _ greenLocations:Array<CGPoint>, _ redPatterns:Array<Array<String>>, _ redSize: CGFloat, _ redLocations:Array<CGPoint>, _ orangePatterns:Array<Array<String>>, _ orangeSize: CGFloat, _ orangeLocations:Array<CGPoint>)->Bool {

    var passLevel = true
    var current = 0
    let currentTestIndicator = SKSpriteNode()
    currentTestIndicator.name = "indicator"
    currentTestIndicator.size = CGSizeMake(0, 128)
    blueLocations[current].y)
    currentTestIndicator.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    currentTestIndicator.zPosition = 0
    node.addChild(currentTestIndicator)

    let patterns = [bluePatterns, greenPatterns, redPatterns, orangePatterns]
    let sizes = [blueSize, greenSize, redSize, orangeSize]
    let locations = [blueLocations, greenLocations, redLocations, orangeLocations]
    let colors = [color("Light Blue 01"), color("Light Green 01"), color("Light Red 01"), color("Light Orange 01")]

    for sets in patterns {
      for rows in sets {
        if rows != [] {
          print("Current set: \(current)")
          print(rows)
          currentTestIndicator.color = colors[current]
          currentTestIndicator.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: locations[current][0].y)
          print(currentTestIndicator.position)
          print("Sizes current = \(sizes[current])")

          let growRight = SKAction.resizeToWidth(sizes[current], duration: 0.2)
          let recurse = SKAction.runBlock() {
            recursion(state, rows, 0, 0, &passLevel)
            current++
            print("Changed current value to \(current)")
          }
          let pause = SKAction.waitForDuration(5.0)
          let shrinkLeft = SKAction.resizeToWidth(0, duration: 0.2)
          let runCheck = [growRight, recurse, pause, shrinkLeft]
          currentTestIndicator.runAction(SKAction.sequence(runCheck))
        }
      }
      current = 0
    }

    currentTestIndicator.removeFromParent()

    print("Ran level check")

    switch passLevel {
    case true:
      print("Level passed")
    case false:
      print("Lavel failed")
    }
    return passLevel
}
```

Comment: I believe that blocks run asynchronously, which is why the code inside `recurse` isn't getting called right away

Comment: Did you add `currentTestIndicator` to the scene (or a node that is in the scene)?

Comment: But `growRight` and `shrinkLeft` aren't getting called either, that I can see. If I replace `runBlock` with `SKAction.waitForDuration(5.0)`, I still don't see the `resizeToWidth` actions take place.

Comment: @0x141E, I did add it to a node in the scene. If you would like me to post more of my code, I'll do it. I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere inside this block, but obviously if I knew exactly what was wrong I wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: I suggest you post the code that adds `currentTestIndicator` to the scene and the code that defines `current` and `sizes` .

Comment: @0x141E, I added the code for the full function. I've checked that the values for current and sizes are correct, but even when I replace them with numbers instead of variables, it still doesn't run how it is supposed to.

Comment: Try deleting the `currentTestIndicator.removeFromParent` statement.

Comment: @0x141E, that worked for getting the code to run, if you want to submit it as an answer, I'll mark the question as answered. If not, I'll answer the question myself. I'll probably be creating a new question about how to run SKActions sequentially with lines of code.